# Django, from php to Django

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-302

I have a website done with Django, that was previously done with PHP and CodeIgniter. I've moved the website to Webfaction, changed the DNS and all other configurations, but now my email is full of errors like this:

```
Error (EXTERNAL IP): /index.php/main/leer/7497
```

I don't know why the Django app is looking for pages from the PHP app, specially since the PHP app was in another host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are those URLs from your old site? That's probably a case of people having stale bookmarks, trying to navigate to them, and getting 404s. You might want to consider catching those, and redirecting to the new URL with response code 302.

I can't imagine those errors are caused by Django (except in the sense that the reports are from Django reporting 404s, which it does for free).

Comment: I'm definitely certain this is the reason.

Comment: Yes, from the old site , Yes Dominic, is reporting 404, i will try the  contrib.redirects

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I agree with above. Just want to add you should use django.contrib.redirects to move the redirects.

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/#ref-contrib-redirects)